# Query Takes 5 Hours on First Run After Docker Restart

Tags: docker, sparql, wikidata, graphdb

I'm using GraphDB version 10.2.0.
I am encountering a performance issue with GraphDB that I hope you can help me with. Here's the situation:

Problem Description:

When I initially run a specific query on wikidata after restarting the GraphDB Docker container, it takes an exceptionally long time, approximately 5 hours, to complete.
However, when I rerun the same query a second time, it completes in a more reasonable time frame, around 9000 milliseconds, which is what I expect it to take.

My Question:
I'm perplexed by why the query takes 5 hours on the first run and only 9000 milliseconds on the second run. Can anyone shed some light on why this might be happening and how can i resolve this issue?

I've taken several steps to diagnose and address this issue:

Docker Container Restart: Initially, I restart the GraphDB Docker container to clear the cache.

Query Execution: After restarting the Docker container, I execute a specific query against my wikidata dataset.

Expected Outcome:

I expected that the query would execute efficiently, taking approximately 9000 milliseconds, as it does on subsequent runs after the Docker container restart.

Actual Result:

Surprisingly, on the first run after Docker container restart, the query takes an unusually long time, around 5 hours, to complete.
Subsequent runs of the same query (after the first one) consistently execute in the expected timeframe, around 9000 milliseconds.

I'm using a command-line approach. However, I've provided the equivalent docker-compose.yml configuration that corresponds to my setup.

services:

graphdb:

```
image: khaller/graphdb-free

ports:

  - "7200:7200"

volumes:
  - <volume_contains_data>:/root/graphdb-import
  - <data_volume>:/opt/graphdb/data

environment:
  GRAPHDB_WORKBENCH_IMPORTDIRECTORY: <volume_contains_data>
  GRAPHDB_HEAP_SIZE: 128g
  JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx64g
```

Comment: Can you provide the necessary pieces of information to create a minimal reproducible example (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case, the `docker-compose.yml`, data entered in the graphdb and the exact sparql query.

Comment: Take a look at the docker logs. I suspect that the image of Wikidata is rebuilding (one or more of the collections) when started and that's why it takes a very long time. Also which version of GraphDB are you using?

Comment: I appreciate your insights. I'm currently running GraphDB version 10.2.0, and I've included the configuration details in my question.